# How to sort the Dataframe by comparing two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I just want to sort Team 1 and Team 2 By comparing them both.

```
       Team 1       Team 2      Winner       Ground
0   Australia      England   Australia    Melbourne
1     England    Australia    England    Manchester
2   Australia      England   Australia         Lord
3     England    Australia    England    Birmingham
4 New Zealand    Australia  Australia       Dunedin
5   Australia  New Zealand  Australia  Christchurch
6       India      England    England         Leeds
7     England        India    England      The Oval
```

After comparing and Sorting it Would be like:

```
       Team 1      Team 2      Winner        Ground
0     England   Australia   Australia     Melbourne
1     England   Australia     England    Manchester
2     England   Australia   Australia          Lord
3     England   Australia     England    Birmingham
4 New Zealand   Australia   Australia       Dunedin
5 New Zealand   Australia   Australia  Christchurch
6       India     England     England         Leeds
7       India     England     England      The Oval
```

Comment: Can you add more data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Thank you, what is logic of sorting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need sorting values per rows in descending order only for team columns use [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
df[['Team 1','Team 2']] = np.sort(df[['Team 1','Team 2']], axis=1)[:, ::-1]
print (df)
        Team 1     Team 2     Winner        Ground
0      England  Australia  Australia     Melbourne
1      England  Australia    England    Manchester
2      England  Australia  Australia          Lord
3      England  Australia    England    Birmingham
4  New Zealand  Australia  Australia       Dunedin
5  New Zealand  Australia  Australia  Christchurch
6        India    England    England         Leeds
7        India    England    England      The Oval
```

**Details**:

First sorting in ascending order:

```
print (np.sort(df[['Team 1','Team 2']], axis=1))
[['Australia' 'England']
 ['Australia' 'England']
 ['Australia' 'England']
 ['Australia' 'England']
 ['Australia' 'New Zealand']
 ['Australia' 'New Zealand']
 ['England' 'India']
 ['England' 'India']]
```

And then swap 'columns' by indexing:

```
print (np.sort(df[['Team 1','Team 2']], axis=1)[:, ::-1])
[['England' 'Australia']
 ['England' 'Australia']
 ['England' 'Australia']
 ['England' 'Australia']
 ['New Zealand' 'Australia']
 ['New Zealand' 'Australia']
 ['India' 'England']
 ['India' 'England']]
```